# Why ElasticSearch as a Windows service requires JAVA_HOME to be set?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-8, windows-services

I'm developing a software which uses ElasticSearch. ElasticSearch is based on Java so I need Java JRE 1.8 to be installed on the user PC as part of the installation process. Java 1.8 JRE may or may not be present on the user PC.

I'm trying to understand how to properly install ElasticSearch on the user PC.

I tried installing Java JRE 1.8 on a clean Windows 7 virtual machine. After the installation process, the environmental variable `PATH` get updated with the path to the java.exe executable. This allows to call java.exe from anywhere in the console

ElasticSearch runs just fine when I launch the elasticsearch.bat script, I launch this:

> elasticsearch.bat

I get this (which is fine, ElasticSearch runs correctly):

[image]

However, if I try to install the ElasticSearch service:

> elasticsearch-service.bat install

I need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable beforehand. I can set it on a local scope like this

> SET JAVA_HOME=mypath
>
> elasticsearch-service.bat install

This way the script successfully installs the Windows Service. However, if I try to run the service I get an error stating that `JAVA_HOME` is not set on the system. Looking at the log files I get this error:

[image]

My question is, why ElasticSearch as a Windows service requires `JAVA_HOME` to be set? My reasoning is: java.exe is available system wide (by means of `PATH`) why the Windows service requires `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: have you restarted your User PC once elastic search service is installed?

Comment: Because in script service of elasticsearch expected a variable "JAVA_HOME" to run. Instead of set JAVA_HOME in local scope set in system variable of Windows.

Comment: @BrunoCarletti thanks for the quick reply. But this way I may end up overwriting the current JAVA_HOME of the user (if set) and I may screw up other user java programs. Am I right?

Comment: You can try set in "user variable" instead of "system variable". But now I understood your problem.

Comment: @mannedear yes, same error

Comment: The "...\bin\server\jvm.dll" it's correct? The jvm usually stay in "...\bin\java.exe".

Comment: @BrunoCarletti well, yes... C:\program files\Java\jre1.8.0_162\bin\server\jvm.dll   but of course it doesn't find it because JAVA_HOME is not set. In my case JAVA_HOME should be (C:\Program files\java\jre1.8.0_162)